# Firebase: routing hosting requests to storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

How to route certain read requests (e.g. myapp.web.app/storage/avatar.jpg) to files that is stored in Firebase Storage? Reasons:

- on landing page I want to avoid loading Firebase JS libraries until user logs in
- be able to share certain user generated data on social networks
- don't want user to see link https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp/o/file.json?alt=media&token=b19976f7-c211-2299-bac7-d5e9f4448acc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible just with any of the [configuration options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config) available for Firebase Hosting.  Best you could do is rewrite a URL to Cloud Functions or Cloud Run, where you have code to download the content from Stroage and send that to the client.

- [Route to Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#direct_requests_to_a_function)
- [Route to Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#direct_requests_to_a_cloud_run_container)

Comment: Thank you, but this was something I was trying to avoid as function calls are billed and I expect significant number of these requests. Also one other usage was to offload some of the requests to Firestore by having prepared JSONs but if it would eat up Functions than I would have to look somewhere else for optimization or I would have to live with having these long links.

Comment: A Cloud Function invocation is exceptionally cheap.  You get 2 million for free every month, and they cost a fraction of a fraction of a penny each from there on.  And it's your only option if you're hosting with Firebase and don't want to expose storage URLs.

Comment: Oh, and it gets cheaper if you work the Firebase Hosting CDN cache correctly so that future invocations for the same URL don't even have to hit the function again.

Comment: Interesting, I'm checking it right now. Maybe I'm dragging too long, but what would be the best approach if you wanted to offload Firestore reads? What would be the prefered way to cache them and does my idea of using Storage makes any sense?

Comment: Those questions are kind of broad.  If you want to start up a general open-ended discussion, Stack Overflow isn't really great for that, but a discussion forum such as Reddit is. https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/

Comment: Thank you. Not exactly what I wanted to hear but it will help me towards the right direction.